# Realm Model update from other thread but should notify adapter

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

I am sending message from adapter to Websocket in websocket onReponse method i am updating Realm Model class but process is going in background and not moving to forward  :
here you can look my code :

public static void updateMsgStatus(String userId, 
                                    String messageId, 
                                   MSG_STATUS msgStatus) {

```
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    Message message = realm.where(Message.class)
            .equalTo(Message.USER_ID, userId)
            .equalTo(Message.MESSAGE_ID, messageId).findFirst();

    realm.beginTransaction();
    message.setMsgStatus(msgStatus.ordinal());
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(message);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

In this line  message.setMsgStatus(msgStatus.ordinal()); after nothing do going in background but i am waiting here :

if i am creating my own thread in this method then realm will not notify adapter 
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Please user RealmChangeListener() for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use use a **change listener** on the realm instance where your data is bound/rendered, Docs [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-threading-example). 
As I'm sure you would imaging this notifies changes to objects that you have subscribed to.

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmResults<Message> messages = realm.where(Message.class).findAllAsync();

messageChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange() {
        // update your dataset
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
messages.addChangeListener(messageChangeListener);
```

Comment: @pradeepbishnoi No probs :)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of adapter are you using ?
If this is the default one you can try just use something like

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(positionOfItemToChange);
        }
    });
```

Comment: but message is coming in background so here i have not activity in this method and i am using  this RealmBaseAdapter<Message>

Comment: you can use a context obj ti run this scope. For example you can pass context instance as a param to a class where you are trying to update you Message and use it like this:
context.runOnUiThread